# Jupyterlab doesn't display some cells visible in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

Jupyterlab search function is not working properly. It finds patterns but doest jump to them as in the gif bellow. The pattern is obviously in the notebook, confirmed with `grep`.
This happen with all notebooks. Sometime when the pattern is displayed on the same page. It does finds it and jumps to it. The behavior is the same in code or markdown cell and also in the notebook checkpoint file.
When the notebook is opened in the classic notebook, the cells are visible.
I have deleted all other cells and save only one of the problematic cells. That cell is now visible in jupyterlab!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me it seemed to be that the jupyterlab toc extension wanted nodejs 12+ which isn't available from the standard conda channels at the moment.

This fixed it for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
```